# How to refresh the json I get through $http.get without drawing my highchart again and again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, highcharts

As you can see in my code I am calling my Highcharts function inside the  $http.get itself and pass the JSON as parameters since my variable becomes undefined if I use it outside the $http.get. Now I want to refresh my data every 30 seconds but since I use drilldown I don't want my graph to be redrawn every single time.

```
var getChartData = function() {
    return $http.get("./AlertsJsonCreation").success(function(response) {
        $scope.jsonChart = response;                                
        console.log("Inside refresh", $scope.jsonChart);
    });
};

$interval(function() {
    getChartData();
}, 5000);

getChartData().then(function(response){
    console.log("Refresh then", $scope.jsonChart);
    DealerChart($scope.jsonChart.dealer, $scope.jsonChart.dealerDrilldown);
});

function DealerChart(dealer, drilldown) {
    ...
    series: [{
        name: 'Regions',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: dealer
    }],    
    drilldown: {
        series: drilldown
    },
    ....
}
```

Comment: try to use .refresh() and .reflow() in highcharts

Comment: Can you give an example stating how I can use it.

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.redraw. You can check the docs. If you just want to update the series data, you can use highcharts series.update (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update).

Comment: You can use dynamic methods for adding data like [Series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update), Series.setData(), Series.addPoint() - see demo with the live data http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/